# image to be moved horizontally as the uislider is moved horizontally in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have taken a view based project.i placed a image on the viewcontroller's view and also a uislider on the same view.my requirement is as i move the uislider, the image should also move in the direction of the slider.for this i understood that if i change the xcordinate with the ratio of uislider's value my task is done.
but i am not able to get the uiimageView or frame cordinates programmatically so that i can manipulate the xcoordinate in my code.
can anyone help in this regard. plz answer me considering that i am new to programming.

thanks a lot in advance
dinakar

Comment: you mean you just want to frame of imageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGRect imageViewFrame = yourImageView.frame;
```

[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) docs. :d